# Error 'exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH Error compiling for board AI Thinker ESP32-CAM.' in Arduino IDE 1.8.12

Tags: esp32, python, ubuntu

I am trying to upload a sketch to the ESP32-CAM board using Arduino IDE 1.8.12 and I get an error message:

```
exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH
Error compiling for board AI Thinker ESP32-CAM.
```

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.4.LTS.

When I type python in the console, it does open python:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

Also python is in one of the directories referenced by PATH:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I added an additional URL referring to the ESP32 boards on the Espressif website:

```
Arduino IDE > File > Preferences > Settings > Additional Boards Manager URLs: > https://dl.espressif.com/dl/package_esp32_index.json
```

Then I added the libraries for all ESP32 boards:

```
Arduino IDE > Tools > Board > Boards Manager > esp32 version 1.0.4
```

(I tried with version 1.0.3 and it didn't change anything...)

I selected my board in the interface:

```
Arduino IDE > Tools > Board > AI Tinker ESP32-CAM
```

I granted all permissions to the USB port:

```
sudo chmod a+rwx /dev/ttyUSB0
ls -la /dev/ttyUSB0
crwxrwxrwx 1 root dialout 188, 0 Mar  4 21:25 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

My sketch is really simple:

```
void setup() {
}

void loop() {
}
```

I get the same error for any example sketch and for any ESP32 board.

Any idea how this could be fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

All right so I was able to fix the problem. The Arduino IDE I was using had been installed from the Ubuntu Software Center. I uninstalled it.

Then I reinstalled the Arduino IDE by downloading it from the www.arduino.cc website and doing a manual install in /opt. Now it works awesome.

Comment: Good, that you solved the problem. You can mark your answer as correct, so that other can see, that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with the old Arduino IDE snap on Ubuntu. You can easily fix this by installing the new [arduino snap](https://snapcraft.io/arduino):

```
snap install arduino
```

Then add your user to the `dailout` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

After this, **reboot your device** and open Arduino IDE.

### Installing additional libraries

The Arduino IDE snap runs inside of a sandbox for security and stability reasons. This means it cannot access the Python libraries on your device. The snap bundles Python 3 and the `serial` library. If you need any other Python dependencies, you can install them inside of the sandbox using the `arduino.pip` command.

```
arduino.pip install <package-name>
```

*Note: do not use `sudo` for this command*